# How to resize and move every window on the desktop using win32 so that it doesn't overlap a menu bar on top of the desktop

Tags: winapi

This is a tricky one. I want to make a program that draws a bar across the top of the desktop. I then want every window that opens up to not draw over this title bar even if a given desktop window is maximized. I remember I saw something similar to this being done but I don't remember the program. I guess those extend taskbar type programs must do something similar to have windows not overlap the extended taskbar on the second monitor.

What framework in windows is require to make this happen? active accessibility to see when windows are created and then somehow get the window handle and resize and position it?

I can iterate through the window list and move them but what about when they open or are maximized?

Any ideas how this behavior is achieved?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx

Comment: Thanks Amazed. A little different case though as he is talking about topmost-ness and I want to resize and move all windows. But, yeah, I need to be on the top of the hierarchy and control things. Heavens, should someone else try... but I can wake up and knock him unconscious, right!? :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called the "work area", defined on MSDN as "the portion of the screen not obscured by the system taskbar or by application desktop toolbars". You can set the work area using the **SPI_SETWORKAREA** action of [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- you want to set this to the existing work area minus the area of your new bar.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to create an AppBar: Windows has built-in support for managing the desktop area, including allowing you to ask it to reserve space for your app along one of the sides. See [MSDN: Using Application Desktop Toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

Summary from MSDN:

> An application desktop toolbar (also called an appbar) is a window that is similar to the Windows taskbar. It is anchored to an edge of the screen, and it typically contains buttons that give the user quick access to other applications and windows. The system prevents other applications from using the desktop area used by an appbar. Any number of appbars can exist on the desktop at any given time.